# Gson nested objects with an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, gson

Having issues taking out data from the internal ArrayList and variables of my Json. I'm able to read in my Json into a string and print it out, but when i call fromJson and access the resulting Class, my arraylist is empty and all the data is blank.

sample codes below.

My Json string print:

```
{

'ShippingList': {

'ShippingInfo': {

'ShipList_No': 'SP10000001',

'Ship_Date': 'Nov-14-2017'
                                                                        },

'ItemInfo': [{

'Item_SerialNumber': 'item0000001',

'Bin_Location': '3',

'QTY': '1'

},

{

'Item_SerialNumber': 'item0000002',

'Bin_Location': '3',

'QTY': '1'

},

{

'Item_SerialNumber': 'item0000003',

'Bin_Location': '3',

'QTY': '1'

},

{

'Item_SerialNumber': 'item0000004',

'Bin_Location': '3',

'QTY': '1'

},

{

'Item_SerialNumber': 'item0000005',

'Bin_Location': '3',

'QTY': '1'

}
]
}
}
```

Gson Code:

```
Gson Gos = new Gson();
ShipList SL = Gos.fromJson(inList,ShipList.class);
String temtem = SL.getALI().get(0).getSerial();
Log.d("Proof! ","wadda " + temtem);
```

this prints nothing only: Proof! wadda

My classes fit what is coming out of the Json and also have been serialized. I have succesfully been able to make a class and make it into Json but i am unable to convert from Json to object properly

Comment: the above json contains error that's why GSON is not parsing it

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your code is that json uses double quotes `"`, not single quotes `'`, for containing keys and values. The first few lines of your json should be

```
{
  "ShippingList": {
    "ShippingInfo": {
      "ShipList_No": "SP10000001",
```

and so on.

I tested this as correctly formatted json with gson version 2.7 on my own machine and it worked fine

```
Gson Gos = new Gson();
//set inList to your input .json
ShipList SL = Gos.fromJson(inList,ShipList.class);
String temtem = SL.shippingList.itemInfo.get(0).itemSerialNumber;
System.out.println(temtem);
```

and it printed out `item0000001`. If you fix the formatting of your json and it still doesn't work some other things I would check is that `inList` is being correctly initialized to contain your json text.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks mate! i changed the ' to " and it begun to work like a charm. Can't believe i made such a mistake!